# Should I dispatch multiple actions in a single action creator, or change multiple properties in a single action type?

Tags: redux

Say you are fetching data from a database - is it better to use an action creator like:

```
dispatch(fetchDataStart());

//then on success

dispatch(fetchDataSuccess(data));
```

And then have the reducer part look like:

```
case FETCH_DATA_START:
    return { ...state, isFetching:true };
case FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
    return { ...state, isFetching:false, data:action.data };
```

Or is it better to separate the fetching-logic from the data-logic and do something like this:

```
dispatch(fetchDataStart());

//then on success

dispatch(fetchDataFinish());
dispatch(updateData(data));
```

reducer:

```
case FETCH_DATA_START:
    return { ...state, isFetching:true };
case FETCH_DATA_FINISH:
    return { ...state, isFetching:false };
case UPDATE_DATA:
    return { ...state, data:action.data };
```

Answer (score 0):

The initial. The latter doesn't make much sense unless it's executed async. 
Normally you would use an action to describe your intent `fetchData` is a reasonable name. A reducer will set the state to loading. Than the middleware will run with the the action and afterwards the middleware will trigger an action to inform the fetch is done, something like `fetchSuccess` and `fetchError`. You're allowed to do whatever is in the middle. If you want to trigger a `FETCH_DATA_LOADING` action after your `fetchData` action, because you have need for a very cool reducer to listen for it, please do so.The same argument for when the middleware returns. Please keep your actions as generic as possible so the middleware logic can be reused.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Actually, I did intend that the code would be async. Does this mean that it makes sense to do it the second way? My intent was to make action creators describe what the application is doing and have reducer types describe what is being done to the store.

Comment: There is no rule of thumb here. An action is either picked up by a middleware or by an reducer (or both). You can handle these however you want. A widely used pattern for async actions is: `ACTION` -> `ACTION_LOADING` -> `ACTION_SUCCESS`/`ACTION_ERROR`